# Backslash character before "lines" - print function in Python3

Tags: printing, python-3.x

I'm having a tough time with this issue. Every time I try to get backslashes in this program it only gives me an error.

the line I want is

```
print(day,\\month,\\year"is a magic date")
```

but no matter how often I try something else, nothing seems to work. Any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: What would you expect those backslashes to do?

Comment: seperate the day month and year in the following format 6/10/60

Comment: If you want to print forward slashes, I can't imagine why you put backslashes in your question... But ok, that explains what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to what Oz123 already wrote, you might want to use string formatting:

```
print('{}/{}/{} is a magic date'.format(day, month, year))
```

Comment: @Nick: `print(r'{}\{}\{} is a magic date'.format(day, month, year))` for backslashes (e.g., in a Windows path). Both date formats are ambiguous. `YYYY-MM-DD` could be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Python the "\" is a string:

```
>>> print(day, "\\", month, "\\", year, "\\", "is a magic date") 
1 \ Sep \ 1978 \ is a magic date
```

You could also specify the sperator:

```
>>> print(day, "\\", month, "\\", year, "\\", " is a magic date", sep=" ")
1 \ Sep \ 1978 \ is a magic date
```

or simply do:

```
>>> print(day ,month, year, " is a magic date", sep="\\") 
1\Sep\1978\ is a magic date
```

Comment: oh. Thank you very much. I didn't even think of that. I had tried every other combination.